# Setting Dynamic base URL in CodeIgniter 4.0.2

Tags: codeigniter, php-7, base-url, codeigniter-4

I am migrating my project from CodeIgniter 3 to CodeIgniter 4. I am getting confused for the new structure of the framework. So here's my problem,

I am setting my base url in **App.php** to:

```
protected $proj_root= "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
protected $proj_root2  = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
protected $mybase= $proj_root.$proj_root2;
public $baseURL =  $mybase;
```

But I am getting error like this:

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in D:\xampp\htdocs\delivery_dashboard\app\Config\App.php on line 26

So literally I can only do this:

```
public $baseURL = "http://localhost/my_project/"
```

How can I set my base url dynamically using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or is there any workaround here?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I dont know the exact solution but i shared my way of solution to you 
>     Go to app/Config/**Constants.php**

```
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    defined('BASE') || define('BASE',$protocol);
```

> In app/Config/**App.php**

```
 public $baseURL    = BASE;
```

> Hope this Helps

Comment: Is it the best way to define base url as constant?

Comment: This worked just fine. But is it secure to use?

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/Config/Constants.php and open it in your IDE. Then place this below code in the end of your file.

```
if ( (! empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] == 'https') ||
     (! empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ||
     (! empty($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == '443') ) {
    $protocole = 'https://';
} else {
    $protocole = 'http://';
}

$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
$project = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$baseurl = $protocole . $host . $project[1];
$myappBaseUrl = $baseurl.'/';
defined('BASESEURL') || define('BASESEURL',$myappBaseUrl);
```

and now open app/Config/App.php and replace
This

```
public $baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/';
```

with

```
public $baseURL = BASESEURL;
```

Comment: Why the code is so big? Could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Improved answer of Boominathan

app/Config/Constants.php

```
$protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."".str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
defined('BASEURL') || define('BASEURL',$protocol);
```

In app/Config/App.php

```
public $baseURL = BASEURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app/Config/Constants.php` and add the following line of code at end of the file.

```
$base_url = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') || isset($_ENV['FORCE_HTTPS'])) ? 'https' : 'http';
$base_url .= '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '',   $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
defined('BASESEURL') || define('BASESEURL', $base_url);
```

Then go to in `app/Config/App.php`, apply `BASESEURL` to `$baseURL` variable

```
 public $baseURL = BASESEURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Checked and working for dynamic baseURL and for PHP spark serve

```
defined('BASE_URL') OR define('BASE_URL', (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off'  ? 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : 'http://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) . '/');
$config['base_url'] = BASE_URL;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is will help you to add directory if any, and will also add trailing slash. This is very useful when you work on localhost as well as online i.e CI/CD.

`app/Config/Constants.php`

```
$base_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) . (substr(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), -1) == '/' ? '' : '/');

defined('BASE_URL') || define('BASE_URL', $base_url);
```

`app/Config/App.php`

```
public $baseURL = BASE_URL;
```